# PHP Notice: Uninitialized string offset

Tags: php, string, offset

I have an error in my code it says 
PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 14 on line 9

This is line 9:

```
while($url[$i]!='/' && $url[$i]!='?' && $i<$len)
```

What to do to avoid this?

Here is the full code in case you need it:

```
 function remove_extra_in_url($url)
{
    $extra=array('https://','http://','www.',' ');
    $url=strtolower($url);
    $url=str_replace($extra,'',$url);
    $i=0;
    $site_name='';
    $len=strlen($url);
    while($url[$i]!='/' && $url[$i]!='?' && $i<$len)
    {
        $site_name.=$url[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    return $site_name;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the last character, it will be checking the character before checking there is a character to test.  Moving `$i<$len` will stop any further checks once this condition is false due to using `&&`...

```
while($i<$len && $url[$i]!='/' && $url[$i]!='?')
```

Comment: Thank you Nigel Ren I will try this and rate your answer if helped!

Comment: do you maybe can also fix this I get error here too: list($type,$rec,$gets,$ref)=explode(':',$data[0]);

Comment: I am getting there Undefined offset: 1, Undefined offset: 2, Undefined offset: 3 errors